# Visual Studio 2010: how to automatically copy files into debug directory

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've got a dll, into which I've inserted txt files into the names subdirectory
[image]

When I build the solution, VS does not create the directory and does not copy the files themselves into the directory of the exe file, which references the dll library

Is there an easy way to make it do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should do that, provided that you have a reference for the class library project in your executable project.  I just setup a scenario like this in Visual Studio 2010:

1. Created a C# Console Application project
2. Created a C# Class Library project
3. Added a Reference to the C# Class Library project into the Console Application project.
4. Added a folder to the C# Class Library project called 'Files'
5. Added a Text File to the 'Files' folder called 'File1.txt'
6. Set the Text File 'File1.txt' 'Copy to Output Directory' property to 'Copy Always'
7. Did a 'Build Solution' and looked in the bin directory of my Console Application and low and behold there was a folder called 'Files' and within it, a file called 'File1.txt'

Maybe you are missing a project reference to your class library in your exe?

Comment: ok. that's strange. probably vs bug or something. the files won't copy in this particular solution

Comment: I am running 2010 SP1 if that matters.

Comment: You should never set anything to "Copy Always".  The "Copy Always" option should not even exist.  Always use "Copy if newer".  Only use "Copy if newer".  Otherwise, you build your project, it does whatever it has to do, and then if you immediately build once more, it has work to do again.  A project build must have zero work to do if it is up to date.