# Icon not found after published?

Tags: c#

I added an icon in **Properties -> Application -> Icon**. Then I built it in release mode and sent the package to another person. When he runs the application, it gives a notification "not find ic-logo.ico.deploy".

I don't know why this happened. Please help me.

Comment: Did you have the properties of that icon file set "Copy Always" ?

Comment: Hi @sam. The properties of that icon set "Resource and Copy Always". But it isn't work

Comment: Hi @PhongNguyen, thanks for your help. My application is Windows Form, not websites

Comment: Could you go to Project Properties => Publish and check whether this Icon file in the list of Application Files are not.

Comment: ".ico.deploy" is a very odd filename extension for an icon file.  Do very strongly favor Project > Properties > Resources, that way the icon gets embedded in the executable file and you can't forget to deploy it or give it an oddball name.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should do it by these steps like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-an-application-icon-visual-basic-csharp?view=vs-2019)

Secondly, Make sure that you have marked the property of icon file to "Copy Always".
Read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186059/visual-studio-2010-how-to-automatically-copy-files-into-debug-directory/9186320) to more details.